# How to get the absolute path of a file in iOS files app and use it later to open the same file

Tags: ios, icloud

So basically I need to copy the path of one PDF file in my iCloud drive (through iOS Files app) and use it as a hyperlink in one of my notes apps to run that file again.

The collaboration sharing function in iCloud doesn’t help as I have to download the file rather than open directly in my PDF reader.

Any ideas?